# Formatting word list from a file into columns

Tags: python, formatting

I have the following function that gets unique words from a python file:

```
def add_unique(s, word_list):
  for word in s.strip().split():
    word = word.lower()
    if word not in word_list:
        word_list.append(word)
```

and if I call it from the main function like this:

```
myFile = open("gameofthrones.txt", "r")

 words = []

for line in myFile:

  print(add_unique(line, words))

myFile.close()

print("Unique words in my file are: ")
for word in words:
   print(word)
```

This prints all of the unique words in one single column, and I was wondering how I could print all the words in the list in 3 separate columns? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by column?

Comment: You can add them in a list, slice the list every three elements and them print each row of these elements. But, could you provide some sample data from your text file and the desired output of those?

Answer (score 2):

You can use method `ljust` of `str`, following way:

```
words = ['some','example','words','for','testing']
longest = max(map(len,words))
for w in [words[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(words),3)]:
    print(' '.join([j.ljust(longest) for j in w]))
```

output is:

```
some    example words  
for     testing
```

Note that this approach adjust to longest word in your `list`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the list of `words`, using slicing, printing every three elements together, like this:

```
print("Unique words in my file are: ")
for i in range(len(words)-2):
    print(words[i:i+3])
```

You can even further format the output, maybe using something like this:

```
print("Unique words in my file are: ")
for i in range(len(words)-2):
    print("{} - {} - {}".format(*words[i:i+3]))
```

Or using advanced formatting to align the output:

```
print("Unique words in my file are: ")
for i in range(len(words)-2):
    print("{:10} - {:10} - {:10}".format(*words[i:i+3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use default overloaded operators for strings. Here is an example (`"\t"` means tab):

```
words = ["Xander", "Spec", "Meng", "Sparc", "Jones", "Nick", "Link", "Xander", "Spec", "Meng"]
print("Unique words in my file are: ")
word_temp=""
i=1
for word in words:
    if (i%3!=0):
        word_temp+=word+"\t"
    else:
        word_temp+=word
        print(word_temp)
        word_temp=""
    i+=1
print(word_temp)
```

This will results in printing every three `words` in any line, separated with tabs:

```
Unique words in my file are:
Xander  Spec    Meng
Sparc   Jones   Nick
Link    Xander  Spec
Meng
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```py
words = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for index, word in enumerate(words):

    # For every 3rd occurrence
    if not (index + 1) % 3:
        print(word, end='\n')
    else:
        print(word, end='\t')
```

Output

1     2        3 
4     5     6

based on @karls inputs changed space differences to tabs

Comment: Ending word with with simple space is not the best idea if you don't know word lenght. "\t" is much better in this case.